# Django - get_or_create triggers RunTimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: django, recursion, init, depth

This is my first post on stackoverflow, so any criticisms about how I ask the question are welcome.

In my code, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Here is the code (the content is irrelevant, I just recreated the error in the simplest way possible). Basically I am trying to override __init__. I want to do something if the object is in the database and something else if it is not.

```
class Question(models.Model):

    text = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    asked = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __init__(self, text, *args):
        #called the __init__ of the superclass.
        super(Question, self).__init__()

        self, c = Question.objects.get_or_create(text=text)
        if c:
            print 'This question will be asked!'
            self.asked = True
            self.save()
        else:
            print 'This question was already asked'
            assert self.asked == True
```

The error occurs when calling the constructor:

```
Question('how are you?')
```

I understand that the problem comes from the get_or_create method. Looking at the error message,

```
---> 12         self, c = Question.objects.get_or_create(text=text)
...
---> 146         return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs)
...
---> 464                 obj = self.model(**params)
```

get_or_create calls the constructor of the object at some point. Which then calls get_or_create again etc...

EDIT: What I would like to achieve is basically being able to write:

```
Question('How are you?')
```

and having the object returned if it's in the database, or the newly created (and saved) one if it's not. Instead of something like:

```
> try:
>     q = Question.objects.get(text='How are you?')
> except Question.DoesNotExist:
>     q = Question(text='How are you?')
>     q.save()
```

So I guess that the only way to achieve this is by overriding the __init__. Isn't it possible or is it conceptually wrong (or both)? Thanks!

Comment: I think you shouldn't overwrite the __init__ method :)

Comment: What are you trying to do with `self, c = Question.objects.get_or_create(text=text)` ?

Comment: I've just edited my question to make my goal more understandable :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't really try and to this in the `__init__`. (In fact, it's best to leave the `__init__` of Django models well alone.) It should go in the form, or the view.

In any case, you can't overwrite an instance inside itself by assigning to `self` - that's just a local variable like any other and will go out of scope at the end of the method.

Also note that you can use the `defaults` parameter to `get_or_create` to pass default values to be set on the new instance if an existing one is not found:

```
question, created = Question.objects.get_or_create(text=text, defaults={'asked': True})
```

**Edit after question update** Your edit makes it even clearer that `__init__` is really not the place to be doing this. Don't forget, even evaluating a normal queryset will instantiate model objects, which means calling `__init__` - so just getting an instance from the database will run into problems. Don't do this.

Instead, if you really need this to be provided by the model - even though it's just one line of code, as shown above - you could define a classmethod:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def query(cls, text):
         question, _ = cls.objects.get_or_create(text=text, defaults={'asked': True})
         return question
```

Then you could do `Question.query('How are you')` and it would return either the new or the existing item.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for pointing out that overwriting an instance inside itself is pointless! However, I would really like to be able to overwrite the \__init__ method (eventhough it's not advised :-)) to be able to write something like Question('myquestion') and having it return the instance + doing some db work behind the scenes. I've edited my question to make my goal clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The logic within your `__init__` needs to be moved somewhere else, like to a view. `get_or_create` returns two values: 1) the object and 2) if the object had to be created or not. [See the docs for more details.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

```
def some_view(request):
    c, created = Question.objects.get_or_create(text=text)

    if not created:
        print 'This question was already asked'
    else:
        print 'This question will be asked!'
        c.asked = True
        c.save()
```

Comment: Thanks Scott! I understand that all the problem would go away if I moved that part of the code into another function or method (like my_init). However, I'm really trying to override \__init__ to be able to write q = Question('myquestion'). I've edited my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Scott Woodall said, you need to move you init logic.
that is What's happening:

When you call `Question('how are you?')`, you go to `__init__` method.
The `__init__` calls `Question.objects.get_or_create(text=text)`, who does't find a `Question` with that `text`, so try to create a new Question, calling `__init__` (again). 
You are re-entering in the method call forever.

```
Question('how are you?') # <-- You call this method
  |
  +-- def __init__(self, text, *args): 
      |
      +-- Question.objects.get_or_create(text=text) # This try to create a model, calling __init__ method!
          |
          +-- def __init__(self, text, *args): 
              |
              +-- Question.objects.get_or_create(text=text) # This try to create a model, calling __init__ method!
                  |
                  +  # So on...
```

I think you should add a `unique=True` to text Question field.

See the @Scott answer

Comment: Thanks for your time lalo. This is indeed what is happening! However, this does unfortunately not solve the problem of how to override \__init__ so that I could just write Question('myquestion') and having some db work done behind the scenes. I've edited my question to make it clearer.